# Extra /**/ in facebook profile picture json

Tags: json, facebook

Im trying to retrieve the URL for a facebook users profile pic. The call returns the JSON I expect as per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#json with one problem - if I specify callback=profile I get a /**/ at the start of the line. Unfortunately this is causing the JSON parser (lift-json) I am using to throw an exception.

Is there a way to stop the /**/ being returned? It seems odd but I cant see any reason its happening and thus see no way to turn it off.

The problem I am facing is shown below using curl.

```
andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ doctorb$ curl "http://graph.facebook.com/582931709/picture?redirect=false&type=normal"
{"data":{"url":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-ash4\/274518_582931709_901337157_s.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}

andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ doctorb$ curl "http://graph.facebook.com/582931709/picture/redirect=false&type=normal&callback=profile"
    /**/ profile({"data":{"url":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-ash4\/274518_582931709_901337157_s.jpg","is_silhouette":false}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first request is for simple JSON and your second request is for a JSONP formatted response.

Facebook adds a comment at the beginning of their JSONP response to prevent a vulnerability called "JSONP hijacking" in the web browser. As any requests to graph.facebook.com will include Facebook cookies, the comment will prevent malicious websites from simply including the request in a script tag and surreptitiously acting on behalf of the authenticated user.

If you want to use the JSONP request, instead of the simple JSON request, you will need to strip out the comment at the beginning of the response before passing it along to your JavaScript parser.

Comment: I hadnt picked up the 2nd request was returning jsonp. Thank you so much for a clear answer!